# Django multiple queries with foreign keys

Tags: python, mysql, django, prefetch

Let's say I have two different apps :

```
teacher/models.py:

  Teacher(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=300)


class/models.py:

  Class(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
     teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
     students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

I want to get all the teachers with classes and all classes attached.

The result I want:

```
{[
   teacher: '3L' #Teachers Id
   classes: ['20L','14L','30L'] #list of Class objects or ids with the above teacher
],
[# similar to above]

}
```

Is this possible to do? This is what I am currently doing:

```
classes = Class.objects.all()
teachers = Teacher.objects.filter(id__in=classes.value_list('teacher',flat=True).distinct())
for teacher in teachers:
    classes_for_teachers = classes.objects.filter(teacher=teacher)
```

In the above code, there are four queries made with a loop which certainly increases the time complexity. Is there a better solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related):

```
teachers = Teacher.objects.prefetch_related('class_set')

# what you want is not a valid Python structure (set of lists (looking like dicts))
# list of dicts makes more sense
result = [
    {'teacher': t.pk, 'classes': t.class_set.all()}
    for t in teachers
]
```

This will only trigger 2 db queries regardless of how many teachers and classes there are.

Comment: What is the class_set? Is it the list of classes?

Comment: `{modelname}_set` is the default `related_name` by which you can access the manager of the reverse relation.

Comment: Can we remove empty list for those teachers who have no classes in the same query? Because looping through them will also increase the time complexity.

Comment: Can we custom query on classes as the argument for prefetch_related?

Comment: Yes, you can pass it a [Prefetch object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) that can contain a custom query on the related model. You should read the linked documentation from the answer =)

Comment: Yeah, I used Prefetch to pass custom query

Comment: Is there a way we can exclude all the teachers which has class_set as an empty list in the same query?

Comment: @AnkitSingh You can insert `.filter(class_set__isnull=False)`

Comment: I tried that already. It says Field Error: Cannot resolve keyword 'class_set' into field

Comment: @AnkitSingh Then try just `class__isnull=False`

Comment: That doesn't work properly. It returns all the teachers and not like how I want that dictionary