# Django - Filter the prefetch_related queryset

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, prefetch

I am trying to reduce my complexity by doing the following. I am trying to get all the teachers in active classrooms.

```
teacher/models.py:

Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)


classroom/models.py:

Classroom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

admin/views.py

teachers = Teacher.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('classroom_set',queryset=Classroom.objects.filter(status='Active'))


for teacher in teachers:
    classrooms = teacher.all()
    # run functions
```

By doing this I get teachers with classrooms. But it also returns teachers with no active classrooms(empty list) which I don't want. Because of this, I have to loop around thousands of teachers with empty classroom_set.  Is there any way I can remove those teachers whose classroom_set is [ ]?

This is my original question - 
[Django multiple queries with foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734174/django-multiple-queries-with-foreign-keys/52734252)

Thanks

Comment: What if a teacher has one active and one passive classroom?

Comment: Can you provide the models to this?

Comment: What is "classroom" in this? What defines if a classroom is active?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Classroom` instead of `Class`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah my bad. Guys Classroom and Teacher are two different apps

Comment: @AnkitSingh: the fact that there are two different apps does not matter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want all teachers with at least one related *active* class, you do not need to prefetch these, you can filter on the related objects, like:

```
Teacher.objects.filter(class__status='Active').distinct()
```

If you want to filter the `classroom_set` as well, you need to combine filtering as well as `.prefetch_related`:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Teacher.objects.filter(
    class__status='Active'
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('class_set', queryset=Class.objects.filter(status='Active'))
).distinct()
```

Here we thus will filter like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT teacher.*
FROM teacher
JOIN class on class.teacher_id = teacher.id
WHERE class.status = 'Active'
```